# File format storing bind pose joints in parent space

Tags: armature, file-format

Do you know of any text file formats (human readable) that blender can export to **store the bind pose bones/joints with the offsets and rotations** (in quaternions) in parent space?

*I know this question is very specific, but I don't know where else to ask.*

#### Example:

[image: Example]

**Note:** I know that the example is 2D and uses euler rotations but its just to show the different spaces.

Comment: By 'text file formats' you mean _human readable file formats_?

Comment: Yes, I do mean human readable.

Comment: I don't expect any existing exporters would output multiple rotations for each item, you would want a script that exports what you want.

Comment: I only want one rotation, the one in parent space.